# A set function that does not overwrite existing values for array

Tags: arrays, tcl

I often see global variable construction like this:

```
global var
if {![info exists var]} {
    set var "Some default value"
}
```

Or for arrays:

```
global array
if {![info exists array(key)]} {
    set array(key) "Some default value"
}
```

It's a bit long to write. So I write a really basic set function:

```
proc set_if_not_exist { name value } {
    if {![info exist $name ] } {
        set $name $value
    }
}
```

Which is working fine, but when I try to do the same with array, things go bad:

The code

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh
proc my_set { name key value } {
    global $name
    if { ! [ info exist $name($key) ] } {
        set $name($key) $value
    }
}

global my_array

set my_array(a)  "a set value"

my_set my_array a "OK"
my_set my_array b "OK"

puts "a: $my_array(a)\n"
puts "b: $my_array(b)\n"
```

What I want:

```
a: a set value
b: OK
```

What I get

```
can't read "name(a)": variable isn't array
    while executing
"info exist $name($key) "
    (procedure "my_set" line 4)
    invoked from within
"my_set my_array a  "OK""
```

So: **What is the idiomatic syntax to set an array from inside a function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with the answer you found yourself. But if you write the proc as:

```
proc my_set {name value} {
    upvar 1 $name var
    if {![info exist var]} {
        set var $value
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the same proc for regular variables and array elements, just like you're used to with the set command:

```
my_set my_array(a) "a set value"
my_set my_array(a) "OK"
my_set my_array(b) "OK"
```

Then `parray my_array` gives:

```
my_array(a) = a set value
my_array(b) = OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
proc my_set { name key value } {
    global $name
    if { ! [ info exist [set name]($key) ] } {
        set $name($key) $value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do what I wanted: the usage of `upvar` is needed:

```
proc my_set { name key value } {
    global $name
    upvar 1 $name arr
    if { ! [ info exist arr($key) ] } {
        set arr($key) $value
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `upvar` to access the array in it's scope, then you don't need `global`

Answer (score 0):

Solutions with `upvar 1` work only when `my_set` procedure called from global namespace. They will fail when this procedure is called from another procedure. The correct and simple solution is:

```
proc my_set { name key value } {
    upvar #0 $name arr
    if { ![info exist arr($key)] } {
        set arr($key) $value
    }
}
```